# What should I call my test for a scoped controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, minitest

I have a controller: `Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` and was wondering what to call the controller test so that the controller is set automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Testing/ConstantLookup/ClassMethods/determine_constant_from_test_name and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize which led me to try Users::SessionsControllerTest which looks odd but works.